# How can I detect linux distribution within GOlang program?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, rhel, oracle-osm

I want to write linux distribution independant Golang code. I need detect which linux distribution and need to run distribution specific commands within program. Like dpkg in case of Ubuntu and rpm -q in case of RHEL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [exec.Cmd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) to run `lsb_release -a` or `uname -a` and parse the output to find out the distribution.

[Reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/)

Comment: lsb_release will do. Thanks. Actually, I was looking if there is go specific functionality.

Comment: The go binary is built with `GOARCH` and `GOOS` as input. The would be no other information available to it about the distribution that it is running on.

Comment: Thanks, I end up using lsb_release.

Comment: lsb_release is not always installed

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to use a Go module, there's [Sysinfo](https://github.com/zcalusic/sysinfo).

It collects all of the system info (without any dependencies) and gives you JSON which includes what you're looking for. Here's a snippet of that data:

```
"os": {
    "name": "CentOS Linux 7 (Core)",
    "vendor": "centos",
    "version": "7",
    "release": "7.2.1511",
    "architecture": "amd64"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The package containing the executable `lsb_release` may or may not be installed on the system.

You could use the file `/etc/os-release`, which can be easily parsed with the library go-ini. See example:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-ini/ini"
)

func ReadOSRelease(configfile string) map[string]string {
    cfg, err := ini.Load(configfile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Fail to read file: ", err)
    }

    ConfigParams := make(map[string]string)
    ConfigParams["ID"] = cfg.Section("").Key("ID").String()

    return ConfigParams
}

OSInfo := ReadOSRelease("/etc/os-release")
OSRelease := OSInfo["ID"]

fmt.Print(OSRelease)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a convenient command line tool backed by a go library here: [dekobon/distro-detect](https://github.com/dekobon/distro-detect)

[Here's how the library is called in the main function of the command line](https://github.com/dekobon/distro-detect/blob/5f5b9c724b9d9a117732d2a4292e6288905734e1/linux/distro.go#L275)

```
linux.FileSystemRoot = fsRoot
distro := linux.DiscoverDistro()
```

It parses both the os-release file and the lsb-release file declarations.